# Concat float with string in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe 'df'. The columns in the dataframe are of the type below -

```
ID         float64
TYPE       object
COMB_ID    float64
AMT_DR     float64
AMT_CR     float64
```

The data in my dataframe looks like -

```
             ID         TYPE              COMB_ID        AMT_DR        AMT_CR      
0       3619998            E                84623       1169456           NaN
1       3619998            E                84624        315792           NaN
2       3619998            E                84625         73389           NaN
3       3619998            E                85947           NaN       1558637
4       3619999            E                84623       1488992           NaN
```

Now, I want to create a new column called 'Status' where in if AMT_DR is not null, then it should create a field like **COMB_ID + 'Dr:'** & same in case AMT_CR is not null. My pandas logic is as below -

```
df['Status'] = np.where(df['AMT_DR'].notnull(), df['COMB_ID'].astype(str) + '-Dr:', df["COMB_ID"].astype(str) + '-Cr:')
```

Now **df** looks like -

```
             ID         TYPE              COMB_ID        AMT_DR        AMT_CR       Status
0       3619998            E                84623       1169456           NaN  84623.0-Dr:
1       3619998            E                84624        315792           NaN  84624.0-Dr:
2       3619998            E                84625         73389           NaN  84625.0-Dr:
3       3619998            E                85947           NaN       1558637  85947.0-Cr:
4       3619999            E                84623       1488992           NaN  84623.0-Dr:
```

So, I dont want the **".0"** part in the **Status** column. Can you please help with the same.

Thanks.

Comment: You could just convert `COMB_ID` to dtype int first so `df['COMB_ID'] = df['COMB_ID'].astype(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice the string like:

```
df["COMB_ID"].astype(str[:-1]) + '-Cr:'
```

or perhaps convert it to an integer.

EDIT: spell check